# How to display two counts using oracle databases?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a list of people and I have to display the count of both male and female entries.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(gender)
  FROM people a
  JOIN accounts b
    ON b.idpers = a.idpers
  JOIN cards c
    ON c.nrc = b.nrc
 WHERE c.category = 'CREDIT'
   AND a.gender = :gender
```

I have tried this and it works, but I want it to display the number of male and female at the same time without the prompt input. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this by group by gender. Here is how you could do this

```
SELECT gender,COUNT(gender)
FROM people a
JOIN accounts b ON b.idpers=a.idpers
JOIN cards c ON c.nrc=b.nrc
WHERE c.category= 'CREDIT' group by gender;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group the query by the `gender`:

```sql
SELECT   gender, COUNT(*)
FROM     people a
JOIN     accounts b ON b.idpers = a.idpers
JOIN     cards c ON c.nrc = b.nrc
WHERE    c.category= 'CREDIT'
GROUP BY gender
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation such as

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 END) AS count_male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'female' THEN 1 END) AS count_female  
  FROM people p
  JOIN accounts a
    ON a.idpers = p.idpers
  JOIN cards c
    ON c.nrc = a.nrc
 WHERE c.category = 'CREDIT'
```

which displays both counts on the same row